# how to shorten js probabilities for functions

Tags: javascript, function, console

i have a js code wanna make it more simple in less steps it working but have many steps
in detail it's function show 3 paramters but if log them in the console them have no sorting for exp
function a(b,c,d){}  it show console.log(a(d,b,c)) there is the code
what it the best practise for this function

```
function show(name="mostafa",age=0,status=true){
    let result;
    let status1= (status == true || age == true || name == true) 
    ? `you are available for hiring`
    : `you are not available for hiring`;
    result= 
    (typeof name == 'string' && typeof age == 'number' && typeof status == 'boolean') // abc
    ?`welcome ${name} your age is ${age} ,${status1}`
    
    :(typeof name == 'string' && typeof status == 'number' && typeof age == 'boolean') // acb 
    ?`welcome ${name} your age is ${status} ,${status1}`
    
    :(typeof age == 'string' && typeof name == 'number' && typeof status == 'boolean') // bac
    ?`welcome ${age} your age is ${name} ,${status1}`
    
    :(typeof age == 'string' && typeof status == 'number' && typeof name == 'boolean') // bca
    ?`welcome ${age} your age is ${status} ,${status1}`
    
    :(typeof status == 'string' && typeof name == 'number' && typeof age == 'boolean') // cab
    ?`welcome ${status} your age is ${name} ,${status1}`
    
    :(typeof status == 'string' && typeof age == 'number' && typeof name == 'boolean') // cba
    ?`welcome ${status} your age is ${age} ,${status1}`
    :`damn !!`
    return result
}
console.log(show(true,25,'mostafa'))
```

```
function show(name="mostafa",age=0,status=true){
    let result;
    let status1= (status == true || age == true || name == true) 
    ? `you are available for hiring`
    : `you are not available for hiring`;
    result= 
    (typeof name == 'string' && typeof age == 'number' && typeof status == 'boolean') // abc
    ?`welcome ${name} your age is ${age} ,${status1}`
    
    :(typeof name == 'string' && typeof status == 'number' && typeof age == 'boolean') // acb 
    ?`welcome ${name} your age is ${status} ,${status1}`
    
    :(typeof age == 'string' && typeof name == 'number' && typeof status == 'boolean') // bac
    ?`welcome ${age} your age is ${name} ,${status1}`
    
    :(typeof age == 'string' && typeof status == 'number' && typeof name == 'boolean') // bca
    ?`welcome ${age} your age is ${status} ,${status1}`
    
    :(typeof status == 'string' && typeof name == 'number' && typeof age == 'boolean') // cab
    ?`welcome ${status} your age is ${name} ,${status1}`
    
    :(typeof status == 'string' && typeof age == 'number' && typeof name == 'boolean') // cba
    ?`welcome ${status} your age is ${age} ,${status1}`
    :`damn !!`
    return result
}
console.log(show(true,25,'mostafa'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best maintainable way would be to pass an object instead, whose destructured properties default to the desired defaults.

```js
function show({ name="mostafa",age=0,status=true } = {}){
  return `welcome ${name} your age is ${age}, you are ${status ? '' : 'not '}available for hiring`;
};
console.log(show());
console.log(show({ status: false }));
console.log(show({ name: 'bob', status: true }));
```

If you're not allowed to do that, I suppose you could collect all arguments into an array, and `.find` each one with the correct `typeof`. Default arguments don't work in combination with when the position of each argument is unknown; you'll have to move that functionality outside the parameter list.

```js
function show(...args) {
  const name = args.find(arg => typeof arg === 'string') ?? "mostafa";
  const age = args.find(arg => typeof arg === 'number') ?? 0;
  const status = args.find(arg => typeof arg === 'boolean') ?? true;
  return `welcome ${name} your age is ${age}, you are ${status ? '' : 'not '}available for hiring`;
}

console.log(show());
console.log(show(false));
console.log(show('bob', true));
```

Answer (score 0):

actually is very simple, compared to your code.

just use an **object** as a parameter:

- the order doesn't matter by default,
- no extra logic is needed

### One Line Code:

```js
function show(obj) {
  return `welcome ${obj.name} your age is ${obj.age} , you are ${obj.status ? '' : 'not'} available for hiring`;
}
```

### Tests:

```js
function show(obj) {
  return `welcome ${obj.name} your age is ${obj.age} , you are ${obj.status ? '' : 'not'} available for hiring`;
}

/* TESTS */

// name, age, status
console.log(
  show({
    name: "mostafa",
    age: 15,
    status: true,
  })
);

// age, name, status
console.log(
  show({
    age: 20,
    name: "ahmed",
    status: true,
  })
);

// status, name, age
console.log(
  show({
    status: true,
    name: "ali",
    age: 10
  })
);

// the combinations can go for ever
```

Comment: i knew that but the problem there not to you objects , just simple math logic i knew that just to use a simple return function but thanks